# How to get Stripe's STPPaymentCardTextField Data programmatically?

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I've successfully set my first view controller to STPAddCardViewController.  I now need to get the user information in the STPPaymentCardTextField. Problem is, I'm used to using the storyboard to make outlets. How do I detect the STPPaymentCardTextField programmatically?

I've tried:

```
class ViewController: STPAddCardViewController, STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {

let paymentCardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()

func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
print(paymentCardTextField.cardNumber)
//ERROR: printing nil in the console
}

}
```

But I'm getting nil as an output. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `STPAddCardViewController`, or `STPPaymentCardTextField`, not both. The SDK's ViewControllers are not designed to be extended. The intended use is:

```swift
class MyVC : STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      …
      let addCardView = STPAddCardViewController()
      addCardView.delegate = self

      // Start the addCardView
      self.navigationController.pushViewController(addCardView, animated: true)
    }

    …
    func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: STPPaymentMethod, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
      // TODO: do something with paymentMethod
      // Always call completion() to dismiss the view
      completion()
    }

    func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
       // TODO: handle cancel
    }
}
```

But rather than my partial example I'd recommend reading [these docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic) and trying out [this example iOS code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example). Best wishes!